# Can I use Eclipse's CSS mechanism to set default styles for custom controls?

Tags: css, eclipse

I've learned a few things about Eclipse CSS `element`, `elementProvider` and `propertyHandler`. Now I have a custom control which needs some default styles.

The simplified control code is as follows:

```java
public class Custom extends Canvas {

    private Color drawColor ;
    
    public Custom( Composite parent ) {
        super( parent, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED ) ;
        super.addListener( SWT.Paint, this :: handlePaint ) ;
    }
    
    private void handlePaint( Event event ) {
        GC gc = event.gc ;
        gc.setAdvanced( true ) ;
        gc.setAntialias( SWT.ON ) ;
        
        if ( drawColor == null ) { return ;}
        gc.setBackground( drawColor ) ;
        // draw something
    }
    
    public void setDrawColor(Color drawColor) {
        this.drawColor = drawColor;
    }
    
}
```

The propertyHandler :

```java
public class CustomPropertyHandler implements ICSSPropertyHandler {
    
    private static final String ATTR_DRAW_COLOR = "draw-color" ;

    @Override
    public boolean applyCSSProperty(Object element, String property, CSSValue value, String pseudo, CSSEngine engine)
            throws Exception {
        Custom custom = (Custom) ((CompositeElement) element).getNativeWidget() ;
        switch ( property ) {
            case ATTR_DRAW_COLOR:
                Color color = (Color) engine.convert( value, Color.class, custom.getDisplay() ) ;
                custom.setDrawColor( color ) ;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

If the following styles are provided in the css :

```css
Custom {
    draw-color: red;
}
```

the `drawColor` is red, but I hope it has a default value like blue.

Inside this control, I can do it like :

```java
    public Custom( Composite parent ) {
        super( parent, SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED ) ;
        super.addListener( SWT.Paint, this :: handlePaint ) ;
        
        this.drawColor = parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor( SWT.COLOR_BLUE ) ;
    }
```

but I prefer to do it with CSS. In other words, there is no style provided for this control in CSS file, but it does have some default styles.

I read some source code and this [tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4CSS/article.html) , but I didn't find the right way.

Comment: That tutorial looks like it covers everything. You need to ask a more specific question

Comment: Also note that a custom control extending something like `Canvas` will inherit all the properties for the extended control - so colours, fonts etc. Usually you only need the extension points to define additional properties not covered by the standard CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do "defaults" in CSS by defining a selector that applies to all of your custom controls and more specific selectors that apply to just the ones that you want to have a different colour:

```css
Custom
{
    draw-color: blue;
    font-family: "SF Pro Semibold";
    font-size: 14pt;
}

.Value
{
    draw-color: red;
}
```

Here controls with the CSS class of `Value` will be red and other Custom controls will be blue. All controls will have the same font-family and font-size.

Note in your example you appear to just be doing the background colour - the standard `background-color` CSS should handle that without needing property handlers. Just be sure to pick up the values in the paint handler GC:

```java
private void handlePaint( Event event ) {
    GC gc = event.gc ;

    gc.setForeground(getForeground());
    gc.setBackground(getBackground());
    gc.setFont(getFont());

    ...
```

If you are drawing the control background yourself you should specify the `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` style in the constructor to stop SWT drawing the default background - which can cause flickering.